# what is the official value of an empty sql result(from a loop)

Tags: php

What I mean is, for example, if I search for something on an SQL table, and it returns 0 / nothing, is that **null** or **empty** or does it result in an empty **""**?

I'm getting back into php and trying to loop through a db like so:

Pseudo code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($var here that has the query to the db and connection)){
      echo $row[//something pulled from table to be read back]
}
```

But let's say that the search query didn't return any results or that `$row` doesn't equal to anything because for whatever reason, the value searched for in the db doesn't exist,

How then can I check for the empty-ness of row?

if the searched for item doesn't exist in the db, then `$rows` value becomes what exactly? **null/empty/or empty string** or something else?

depending on the value of **row**, do I test for **[isset / !isset]** or **[empty / !empty]** ? Or is the ***only*** way to test for empty `$row` to do a  (pseudo) `$x =mysqli_num_rows(var here) / if ($x == 0 ) //do something`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `mysqli_fetch_array` did not return anything, then the return value is `NULL`

The line `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array` is supposed to return the **next** available record in the record set, so if the query did not give any matching results, then the line `echo $row['something']` does not get executed at all.

If there are multiple fields you are fetching, say `field1`, `field2` and supposing `field2` doesn't have a value, then what is returned for that field is what the default value for that field will be in MySQL (or whichever DB you are using). However the point to note is that `$row` will still have two keys defined correctly as `$row['field1']` and `$row['field2']`

If you want to check if `$row['field2']` does have any value you can check it using `empty($row['field2'])`.

`"", 0, NULL, FALSE, array()` are all considered `empty()` so you should be able to safely determine if the field has any valid value in it using this function. However, if say 0 could be a *valid* value (for e.g. you are querying no_of_days a person was absent last month and some of them have full attendance), you will need to explicitly check the value in the field and cannot depend on empty().

Comment: ok but lets say that i want to test the value of $row so that if its "null" then i can print something out...like so if($row == null){  echo "sorry no results avail"; }else { //do something } ....when i test this, the page still comes out blank.

Comment: ive multiple ways and still blank page...i tried something like this ... while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($var here)){
 if(empty($row[""])){ //do something// } else {//do somethng} is this wrong??? ive also tried if(empty($row)) etc but nothing.

Comment: Can you update your question with the actual code you are trying, instead of the pseudo-code? It is easier that way. Also if you are getting a blank page it is because the SQL does not return anything at all, so any `if-else` you write inside the `while` **does not** get executed

Comment: you know what, thanks for all your help, i decided to just roll with an if/else on a num_rows and the while inside of that. BUT you answered my question for the value of $row when no result is retrieved from db. thanks for all the help and clear answer.

Comment: Glad to be able to help, and cool that you got it working! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether there is result using mysql_num_rows. If there is items exist in that row, the row should have show one or more or TRUE depending on the item you searched, if nothing exist in database when you executed the query means the mysql_now_rows will show you 0/NULL.

You can do like

```
$query = mysql_query("YOUR QUERY HERE");
$numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrow == 0)
{
ECHO "No result found.";
}
```

Comment: but lets say that i want to test the value of $row so that if its "null" then i can print something out...like so if($row == null){  echo "sorry no results avail"; }else { //do something } ....when i test this, the page still comes out blank

Answer (score 0):

When there's nothing, $row == false
That's the correct test on the while loop!

Comment: $row is assigned the value returned by mysqli_fetch_array(), then if this result is a false (not an array), the while() loop exit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysqli_num_rows` to fetch the number of results found by a query.

```
$query = 'SELECT `blah`';
$result = mysqli_query($query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // do stuff here if any rows are found
} else {
    // do stuff here if NO rows are found
}
```